# imported data is not showing in search OpenEmpi

Tags: postgresql

I am using Open Empi 3.1.0 and trying to import some files using flexible data loader. I am successfully able to import data but i am not able to search it on search window. Below are the files i used :

**Sample data with tab seperated:**

```
1   15  abc def 1963-08-25 00:00:00.0   M   
1   16  hij klm 2003-07-03 00:00:00.0   F
```

**mapping file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file-loader-map
xsi:schemaLocation="http://configuration.openempi.openhie.org/fileloadermap fileloadermap.xsd"
xmlns="http://configuration.openempi.openhie.org/fileloadermap"
xmlns:fl="http://configuration.openempi.openhie.org/fileloadermap"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
delimiter="\t"
header-first-line="false">
<fields>
<field
datatype="String"
is-identifier="true"
identifier-domain-name="DNO"
namespace-identifier="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1"
universal-identifier="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1"
universal-identifier-type-code="DNO">
<column-index>2</column-index>
<field-name>pid</field-name>
</field>
<field
datatype="String">
<column-index>1</column-index>
<field-name>cid</field-name>
</field>
<field
datatype="String">
<column-index>3</column-index>
<field-name>lastname</field-name>
</field>
<field
datatype="String">
<column-index>4</column-index>
<field-name>firstname</field-name>
</field>
<field
datatype="String">
<column-index>5</column-index>
<field-name>dob</field-name>
</field>
<field
datatype="String">
<column-index>6</column-index>
<field-name>gender</field-name>
</field>
</fields>
</file-loader-map>
```

**After loading data i followed below process:**

1. Rebuild indexes
2. Initialize links
3. Regenerate links
4. Assign global identifiers

**Below is the log entries**

```
[2016-12-19 22:59:12,751] INFO007183[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.SpringEntityLoaderManager.setupConnection(SpringEntityLoaderManager.java:74) - Will be doing an import instead of an add
[2016-12-19 22:59:12,752] INFO007184[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.SpringEntityLoaderManager.setupConnection(SpringEntityLoaderManager.java:90) - Will be doing an import for entity person
[2016-12-19 22:59:12,757] INFO007189[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.SpringEntityLoaderManager.setupConnection(SpringEntityLoaderManager.java:100) - Will be doing a massive import
[2016-12-19 22:59:12,762] WARN007194[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.IntentMassiveInsertImpl.begin(IntentMassiveInsertImpl.java:49) - Removing all indexes.
[2016-12-19 22:59:12,762] WARN007194[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.removeIndexes(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:560) - Droping index idx-person-givenName
[2016-12-19 22:59:13,033] WARN007465[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.removeIndexes(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:560) - Droping index idx-person-familyName
[2016-12-19 22:59:13,252] WARN007684[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.removeIndexes(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:560) - Droping index idx-person-_dirty
[2016-12-19 22:59:13,510] WARN007942[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.removeIndexes(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:564) - Droping index idx-identifier-identifier
[2016-12-19 22:59:13,861] INFO008293[pool-1-thread-2] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.FlexibleFileLoader$RecordLoaderTask.run(FlexibleFileLoader.java:633) - Loading record as: pool-1-thread-2
[2016-12-19 22:59:13,895] INFO008327[pool-1-thread-2] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.FlexibleFileLoader$RecordLoaderTask.saveRecordsInTaskList(FlexibleFileLoader.java:736) - Persisting (4/4/60062) in 32 msec.
[2016-12-19 22:59:17,412] INFO011844[pool-1-thread-2] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.FlexibleFileLoader$RecordLoaderTask.saveRecordsInTaskList(FlexibleFileLoader.java:736) - Persisting (1000/10004/78825) in 220 msec.
[2016-12-19 22:59:19,978] INFO014410[pool-1-thread-2] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.FlexibleFileLoader$RecordLoaderTask.saveRecordsInTaskList(FlexibleFileLoader.java:736) - Persisting (1000/20004/78825) in 235 msec.
[2016-12-19 22:59:32,570] INFO027002[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.loader.FlexibleFileLoader.isDone(FlexibleFileLoader.java:273) - Completed the loader task: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@215e7314
[2016-12-19 22:59:32,602] WARN027034[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.IntentMassiveInsertImpl.end(IntentMassiveInsertImpl.java:68) - Recreating all indexes.
[2016-12-19 22:59:32,604] WARN027036[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.createIndex(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:447) - Creating index: CREATE INDEX idx-person-givenName ON person (givenName) NOTUNIQUE
[2016-12-19 22:59:33,427] WARN027859[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.createIndex(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:447) - Creating index: CREATE INDEX idx-person-familyName ON person (familyName) NOTUNIQUE
[2016-12-19 22:59:33,961] WARN028393[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.createIndex(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:447) - Creating index: CREATE INDEX idx-person-_dirty ON person (_dirty) NOTUNIQUE
[2016-12-19 22:59:35,337] WARN029769[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.createIndex(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:447) - Creating index: CREATE INDEX idx-identifier-identifier ON identifier (identifier) NOTUNIQUE
[2016-12-19 23:00:48,979] INFO103411[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.BlockingServiceImpl.rebuildIndex(BlockingServiceImpl.java:97) - Rebuilding the indices for the Traditional Blocking Service
[2016-12-19 23:00:48,983] INFO103415[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache.dropBlockingClasses(BlockingServiceCache.java:206) - The round is called: BlockingRound [name=round.0, fields=[org.openhie.openempi.configuration.BaseField@6030b2e4[fieldName=patientid]]]
[2016-12-19 23:00:48,983] INFO103415[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.EntityDaoOrientdb.dropClass(EntityDaoOrientdb.java:1104) - Dropping in base class person the class: Blockinground-0
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,542] INFO103974[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.dropClass(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:218) - Class Blockinground-0 was dropped.
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,543] INFO103975[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache.dropBlockingClasses(BlockingServiceCache.java:218) - BlockingServiceCache dropped classes in time: 560
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,543] INFO103975[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache.createBlockingClasses(BlockingServiceCache.java:186) - The round is called: BlockingRound [name=round.0, fields=[org.openhie.openempi.configuration.BaseField@6030b2e4[fieldName=patientid]]]
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,543] INFO103975[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.EntityDaoOrientdb.classExists(EntityDaoOrientdb.java:1010) - Locating in base class person the class name: Blockinground-0
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: OTriggered in cluster -1
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: OSchedule in cluster 7
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: person in cluster 11
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: OUser in cluster 5
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: OIdentity in cluster -1
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: ORole in cluster 4
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: identifier in cluster 12
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: V in cluster 9
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: ORIDs in cluster 8
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: identifierEdge in cluster 13
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: OFunction in cluster 6
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: recordLink in cluster 14
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: E in cluster 10
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,556] INFO103988[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.isClassDefined(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:129) - Class name: ORestricted in cluster -1
[2016-12-19 23:00:49,557] INFO103989[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.EntityDaoOrientdb.createClass(EntityDaoOrientdb.java:1080) - Creating in base class person the class using definition: Entity [entityVersionId=null, entityId=null, versionId=null, name=Blockinground-0, description=null, displayName=null, dateCreated=null, userCreatedBy=null, dateChanged=null, userChangedBy=null, dateVoided=null, userVoidedBy=null]
[2016-12-19 23:00:50,390] INFO104822[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.createClass(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:238) - Class Blockinground-0 has been assigned cluster 15
[2016-12-19 23:00:50,970] WARN105402[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.SchemaManagerAbstract.createIndex(SchemaManagerAbstract.java:447) - Creating index: CREATE INDEX idx-Blockinground-0-blockingKeyValue ON Blockinground-0 (blockingKeyValue) NOTUNIQUE
[2016-12-19 23:00:51,562] INFO105994[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache.createBlockingClasses(BlockingServiceCache.java:200) - BlockingServiceCache created classes in time: 2019
[2016-12-19 23:00:51,570] INFO106002[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache.init(BlockingServiceCache.java:86) - Need to load data for this round.
[2016-12-19 23:01:02,040] WARN116472[Thread-14] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.EntityDaoOrientdb.loadRecords(EntityDaoOrientdb.java:827) - Producer loaded 10000 records.
[2016-12-19 23:01:03,762] INFO118194[Thread-15] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache$RecordConsumerForBlocking.run(BlockingServiceCache.java:129) - Consumer Thread-15 processed 10000 records.
[2016-12-19 23:01:26,650] WARN141082[Thread-14] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.dao.orientdb.EntityDaoOrientdb.loadRecords(EntityDaoOrientdb.java:827) - Producer loaded 20000 records.
[2016-12-19 23:01:30,127] INFO144559[Thread-15] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache$RecordConsumerForBlocking.run(BlockingServiceCache.java:129) - Consumer Thread-15 processed 20000 records.
[2016-12-19 23:01:59,731] INFO174163[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.cache.BlockingServiceCache.init(BlockingServiceCache.java:95) - BlockingServiceCache init time: 70748
[2016-12-19 23:01:59,732] INFO174164[pool-1-thread-4] - org.openhie.openempi.blocking.basicblockinghp.BlockingServiceImpl.rebuildIndex(BlockingServiceImpl.java:108) - Finished building the indices for the Traditional Blocking Service
[2016-12-19 23:03:08,625] INFO243057[pool-1-thread-5] - org.openhie.openempi.matching.exactmatching.DeterministicExactMatchingService.initializeRepository(DeterministicExactMatchingService.java:234) - The deterministic matching service finished initializing the repository for entity person
[2016-12-19 23:50:32,241] WARN086673[pool-1-thread-6] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.impl.RecordManagerServiceImpl.assignGlobalIdentifier(RecordManagerServiceImpl.java:738) - Assigning global ids to block of size 10000
[2016-12-19 23:50:39,272] WARN093704[pool-1-thread-6] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.impl.RecordManagerServiceImpl.assignGlobalIdentifier(RecordManagerServiceImpl.java:738) - Assigning global ids to block of size 10000
[2016-12-19 23:50:47,023] WARN101455[pool-1-thread-6] - org.openhie.openempi.entity.impl.RecordManagerServiceImpl.assignGlobalIdentifier(RecordManagerServiceImpl.java:738) - Assigning global ids to block of size 6275
[2016-12-20 06:49:07,321] INFO201753[http-bio-8080-exec-5] - org.openempi.webapp.server.ReferenceDataServiceImpl.getSystemConfigurationInfo(ReferenceDataServiceImpl.java:216) - The system is configured with blocking algorithm: Traditional Blocking Algorithm (High Performance)
[2016-12-20 06:49:07,322] INFO201754[http-bio-8080-exec-5] - org.openempi.webapp.server.ReferenceDataServiceImpl.getSystemConfigurationInfo(ReferenceDataServiceImpl.java:219) - The system is configured with matching algorithm: Deterministic Matching Algorithm
```

Eveything completes without any error but i am not able to search anything . 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: since "open empi" tag is not available so i used postgresql as in background it uses postgresql

Comment: Also i dont have enough reputation to create a new tag